# Excel formatting - registry modification

Tags: excel, registry

Is it possible to add/modify a key in the registry to set default formatting?  If so, what would it be, and what values to use?

> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options

Comment: What would be default formatting?

Comment: comma style, 2 decimal